# wxPython: Window and Event Id's

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a Panel on which I display a StaticBitmap initialised with an id of 2. When I bind a mouse event to the image and call GetId() on the event, it returns -202. Why?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

        img = wx.Image("img1.png",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel,2,wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        print img2.GetId() # prints 2

        img2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.OnDClick)

    def OnDClick(self, event):

        print event.GetId() # prints -202

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: There's no problem with your code, I just just ran it, your handler prints 2

Comment: @volting: I ran it too and you're right.

Comment: What platform and Python/wxPython versions?

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm using Python 2.6.5 and wxPython 2.8 on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx

Comment: Works fine on mint 9 and windows 7, but on karmic koala I get -202 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the event's ID, not the bitmap's ID.

Try `print event.GetEventObject().GetId()`

`GetEventObject` returns the widget associated with the event, in this case, the `StaticBitmap`.

FWIW, I've never needed to assign ID's to any widgets, and you probably shouldn't need to either.

**Edit**: I saw some other questions you asked and this is what I would recommend, especially if `GetEventObject` is returning the parent instead (I'm very surprised if that's true, you should double check):

```
import functools

widget1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, functools.partial(self.on_left_down, widget=widget1))
widget2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, functools.partial(self.on_left_down, widget=widget2))
# or the above could be in a loop, creating lots of widgets

def on_left_down(self, event, widget):
    # widget is the one that was clicked
    # event is still the wx event
    # handle the event here...
```

Comment: Both event.GetId() and event.GetEventObject().GetId() will return the bitmaps Id http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html#GetId

Comment: @volting: That's not how I interpret the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Yes I may have misinterpreted the linked doc, I cant seem to find anything that better supports my statement, but personal experience tells me they (event.GetId() and event.GetEventObject().GetId()) produce the same result, try it out for yourself

Comment: I tried both the event's GetId() and event.GetEventObject()'s GetId() and they are both producing -202 in the handler. There must be some simple thing I am doing wrong... Thanks for both of your input

Comment: Fogle - you don't use the standard wx.IDs?

Comment: @Steven Sproat: I do use wx.ID_OK, wx.ID_CANCEL, etc. when applicable.  Forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Steven Sproat: FYI - I just answered one of your old questions.